# input password with dart dcli package

Tags: dart

I use the package dcli in dart with the function 'ask' to input a
password. When I enter a password and press 'enter' or 'return' an extra star apears,
but the input does not finish. With every 'enter' apears a star. I can only quit
with pressing Ctrl+C.

What am I doing wrong?

`var passwd = ask('Password', hidden: true);`

Comment: As far as I can see in the `dcli` source code, it does not take into account that on Windows, a newline starts with carriage return (ASCII value 13). I don't know if there are already a bug report on this, but the problem seems to be isolated to when using `hidding: true` since that uses a special logic in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it was a bug.

I fixed it in the latest release.

Comment: thank you very much!